# Examples of subgroups of additive group that aren't subrings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I just started learning about rings, and when playing around with some examples I noticed that in all of them, every subgroup of their additive group was also a subring.
So, I'm looking for examples where that is not the case (a subset of a ring being closed under addition and negatives but not under multiplication).

I tried looking for some but only found a question asking for subgroups of the additive group that aren't ideals.

Comment: Perhaps a silly example depending on what your definition of ring is if you require a ring to have a unit, then the trivial additive group just containing $0$ would be an additive subgroup which is not a subring

Comment: For another super simple example, consider the half-integers $0.5\mathbb Z\subset\mathbb Q$. Those aren't even closed under multiplication.

Comment: The purely imaginary numbers (including zero) are an additive subgroup of the complex numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the examples! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the group of $2\times 2$ real matrices, if you consider the additive subgroup generated by the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &1\\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The additive group it generates is isomorphic to the integers, but it is not a sub ring since if you square the matrix you get
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&2\\ 0&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which is not in the additive group it generates.

Comment: Thanks! I knew there had to be an example with matrices, but my few attempts failed...

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{Z}$ is a ring under normal addition and multiplication but the subgroups $2 \mathbb{Z}$, $3 \mathbb{Z}$, ... $p \mathbb{Z}$ are not (no unity element).

Comment: The question asked about *rings*, not *rings with unity element*.

Comment: That fair I suppose in context that they asked about multiplication closure but the literature is inconsistent and identity is frequently part of the definition of a ring.